# graphically plot confusion matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, confusion-matrix

I have a confusion matrix like this:

```
[1   0   0   0   0 ]
[0  0.9  0  0.1  0 ]
[0   0   1   0   0 ]
[0   0   0   1   0 ]
[0.1 0  0.2  0  0.7]
```

where rows represent ground of truth, columns represent classification result. I would like to plot it graphically in a grid. I tried `surface` but it only shows a 4x4 figure whilst my matrix has 5x5 size.
how can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want your confusion values to define *cell* values instead of *node* values (as `surface` does).

You can use `imshow`for your purpose, maybe combined with some `colormap`.

```
A = [1   0   0   0   0 
     0  0.9  0  0.1  0 
     0   0   1   0   0 
     0   0   0   1   0 
     0.1 0  0.2  0  0.7 ]


imshow(A, 'InitialMagnification',10000)  % # you want your cells to be larger than single pixels
colormap(jet) % # to change the default grayscale colormap
```

[image]

Comment: How can i plot the diagonal values in the box?